# How to print docstring in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

"""
Created on Sat Mar  2 18:44:32 2019

@author: crazyconda
"""

How to print the above content

I want to print the quoted content without the help of obvious command.
I have already read that somewhere but can't find it now.

Comment: what do you mean "help obvious command "

Answer (score 0):

To print `"` you can just use `\"`

```
>>> print("""\"\"\" Created on Sat Mar 2 18:44:32 2019
@author: crazyconda \"\"\"""")

""" Created on Sat Mar 2 18:44:32 2019
@author: crazyconda ""
```

Comment: That's not the question. Spyder auto-generates a string literal at the top of scripts and the OP wants to access the literal

Comment: @roganjosh OP didn't mention that clearly plus i find he done no research regarding that

Comment: Sure, ok. What question does this answer then?

Comment: according to OP wording this is answer. In actual it's not

Comment: that was not the question i asked